# Intro To Logic Stanford course : Lesson 7.8 - Modular Arithmetic

Tags: logic

In this [version of the course](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/lessons/lesson_07_08.html)  it talks about how we can represent Modular Arithmetic in Relational Logic.

I am going to paste the needed content of the course here in case you don't want to open the link.

It first defines the "same" relation which is true of every number and itself and is false for numbers that are different. We can completely characterize the same relation by writing ground relational sentences, one positive sentence for each number and itself and negative sentences for all of the other cases.

```
        same(0,0)       ¬   same(0,1)       ¬   same(0,2)       ¬   same(0,3)
   ¬    same(1,0)           same(1,1)       ¬   same(1,2)       ¬   same(1,3)
   ¬    same(2,0)       ¬   same(2,1)           same(2,2)       ¬   same(2,3)
   ¬    same(3,0)       ¬   same(3,1)       ¬   same(3,2)           same(3,3)
```

Now, let's axiomatize the next relation, which, for each number, gives the next larger number, wrapping back to 0 after we reach 3

```
next(0,1) 
next(1,2)
next(2,3)
next(3,0)
```

Properly, we should write out the negative literals as well. However, we can save that work by writing a single axiom asserting that next is a functional relation, i.e., for each member of the Herbrand base, there is just one successor.

```
∀x.∀y.∀z.(next(x,y) ∧ next(x,z) ⇒ same(y,z))
```

In order to see why this saves us the work of writing out the negative literals, we can write this axiom in the equivalent form shown below.

```
∀x.∀y.∀z.(next(x,y) ∧ ¬same(y,z) ⇒ ¬next(x,z))
```

we can use Relational Logic to define plus in terms of same and next and use that axiomatization to deduce the ground relational sentences. The definition is shown below.

First, we have an identity axiom. Adding 0 to any number results in the same number. Second we have a successor axiom. If z is the sum of x and y, then the sum of the successor of x and y is the successor of z. Finally, we have our functionality axiom once again.

```
∀y.plus(0,y,y)
∀x.∀y.∀z.∀x2.∀z2.(plus(x,y,z) ∧ next(x,x2) ∧ next(z,z2) ⇒ plus(x2,y,z2))
∀x.∀y.∀z.∀w.(plus(x,y,z) ∧ ¬same(z,w) ⇒ ¬plus(x,y,w))
```

what I have understood from the last segment is that we don't have to define the true ground sentences and instead we used this axomization and it should replace the ground sentences.

What I don't understand is, how can an axiomazation like the second in the latter indented segment be true at all (or even false) if we don't define the ground sentences in which it is true?

How does it know if plus(x,y,z) in the second axiom is true without defining it explicitly when it would become true? for example plus(1, 0, 3) is not true.. what am I missing ?
and finally, thank you all for your help.

Comment: $plus(1,0,x)$ is defined by the second axiom: we have (1st axiom) $plus(0,0,0)$ and using the 2nd axiom: $plus(0,0,0) \land next(0,1) \land next (0,1) \land plus (1,0,1)$.

Comment: Thus, applying the 3rd axiom, we have $plus(1,0,1) \land \lnot same(1,3) \to \lnot plus(1,0,3)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you, that makes sense